# how to store the values of the table in cookies

Tags: javascript, cookies, store, key-value-store

https://github.com/palani-08/travelblog/blob/main/html/table.html/table%20submission_files/index.html
[I have attached this file, I'm not able to get the values of the table in cookies]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

localStorage.myTable = document.querySelector('#myTab').innerHTML.trim() // store

document.querySelector('#myTab').innerHTML = localStorage.table // restore